How to effectively find English cognate(s) for a German word?
Is there a web site where I can directly search for all English cognates of a German word?
Currently, I am using a combination of EtymOnline, Wiktionary and DWDS (Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache), but I have to dig inside the content and I don't always get the result.
The ideal solution is to see the word evolution in a clickable tree where you can go back and forward in the history in different languages, something like this:

but a plain text tool connecting only German and English is also acceptable :)
I don't think that Is there a website that can list the English cognates of German words?, however sounding similar, gives exactly what I am asking for, however close it is to it. I'd really find useful something more easily searchable.
N.B.
Someone might object that knowing the cognates is not very useful in learning the vocabulary, however I find it highly helpful. Thanks to knowing the cognates I am able to learn the romance languages much faster, in spite of many false friends. The same applies to German and English.
We remember much more if any new piece of information is connected to other pieces which are already in our head, even if we have to add to some connections the "false friend" label. Using the cognates I even remember better the conjugation of irregular verbs, e.g. without knowing drink-drank-drunk I would have hardly remember trinken-trank-getrunken.

Hi, and welcome here! I don't understand how your question is different from the one you linked, could you elaborate on this?

@JonathanHerrera I tried, see my edit.

Have you tried Appendix:German cognates with English in Wiktionary? It's split into a number of tables (for some reason) according to the sound changes involved, but it might be easier than your current process.
I regard cognates as a convenient memory aid when they exist and have the same meaning, but given that German and English seem to have a larger than expected number of "false friends", and that many German words either have no English cognates at all or have cognates which are very different from the German word, I usually don't put a lot of effort into researching the connections. If you're just trying to learn the vocabulary and not writing a thesis on the history of the two languages, to me it's usually less effort  to just memorize the meaning than try to get there with comparative linguistics. The reason I'm mentioning this is that people tend to create websites where there's a demand, and if knowing all the cognates for a given word in German isn't that useful for an average learner then there might not be a lot of incentive for anyone to create the kind of site you're asking for.
In any case trying to pin down what counts as a cognate and what doesn't can get fairly complicated. As a example I looked at "Geschäft" = "shop". DWDS links this to the verb "schaffen" = "to create/make", but the link between these words isn't obvious. But "schaffen" does have a relatively clear English cognate in "to shape", though the meanings are somewhat different. Meanwhile "shop", which looks like it might be a cognate, actually has a different origin and is really a cognate for "Schuppen" = "shed". So is "shape" a cognate of "Geschäft" or not? The modern meanings are very different and connection is tenuous at best, but there is a common ancestor in there somewhere.

Note that the "ge-" in "Geschäft" once was a productive prefix indicating perfective aspect of a word. For instance: "sitzen" (to sit) is non-perfective but "hinsetzen" (to sit down) is. In Middle High German you didn't say "ich setzte mich hin" but "ich gesaß - the "ge-" indicating that you meant the process of taking place rather than the state of being sat. This, btw., is the same "ge-" nowadays used to build the Partizip Perfekt.

@bakunin - Good to know. The participle is "geschaffen" in modern German, but if you imagine "schaffen" as a weak verb then it might have "geschäft" as a participle, ignoring the ablaut. Nominalization often turns participles into nouns in German, so we have a reasonably plausible explanation for "Geschäft" from "schaffen". That doesn't explain the drastic shift in meaning though. I'm sure there is an explanation, but we're already getting into "too much information" territory from my point of view.

See my edit as my answer to your scepticism related to the usefulness of cognate awareness in the learning process.

@RDBury schaffen exists as a weak verb, with the pariticple geschafft. It might also be interesting (just in case you don't already know) that in Swabian dialect schaffen means "to work", and they use "Geschäft" as "job, office, work". Ich gehe ins Gschäft is "I go to work" in Swabian.

If I would have to guess, there are way more Latin/Roman cognates in English that German ones. So better learn Latin then? :)

@tofro - Latin is supposed to be helpful for Lawyers and Doctors since a lot of the terminology and jargon actually is Latin; possibly that's also true in German speaking countries. But I would say Latin words in English are "borrowed" instead of "cognates".  For an English speaker, reading French can actually be easier than German because French and English borrowed or inherited a lot of the same words from Latin. For example the English "image" is "image" in French (pronounced differently) but "Bild" in German.
